# Error Plugins en proyecto de Spring

Tags: spring, maven

Estoy intentando crear mi primer proyecto con Spring.
Me saltan dos errores:

```
Plugin execution not covered by lifecycle configuration: org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:3.1.0:testResources (execution: default-testResources, phase: process-test-
 resources)
- Plugin execution not covered by lifecycle configuration: org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:3.1.0:resources (execution: default-resources, phase: process-resources)
```

El archivo pom.xml es el siguiente

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org /xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>com.udemy</groupId>
<artifactId>backendninja</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<name>backendninja</name>
<description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

/*ERROR AQUÍ*/<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.0.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: ¿Estás usando Eclipse?

Comment: Sí, Eclipse Oxygen

Answer (score 2):

Es un problema de la integración de Maven con Eclipse (el plugin de Eclipse `m2e`).

En resumidas cuentas, como cualquier otro IDE Eclipse está continuamente recompilando el proyecto para poder ofrecer detección de error, sugerencias de nombres de clases y métodos, tips de documentación, etc.

El problema es que Maven tiene una filosofía de trabajo por bloques: lanzas un proceso y esperas a que acabe. Según como sea tu proyecto, puede tardar un buen rato (p.ej. plugins para generar código automáticamente en función de WSDL u otros recursos, testing, etc.).

Como no quieres que cada vez que guardas un fichero se ejecute todo al menos hasta el *goal* `compile`, y además algunos *plugins* pueden tener memory leaks<sup>1</sup> lo que hace `m2e` por defecto es ejecutar solo determinados *goals*, y mostrar un aviso para los *plugins* asociados a los *goals* que no se van a ejecutar.

En tu caso, esa configuración de los plugins se hereda de `spring-boot-starter-parent`.

La solución para el mensaje de error [viene en la documentación de `m2e`](http://www.eclipse.org/m2e/documentation/m2e-execution-not-covered.html); se trata de configurar el *plugin* `m2e` para indicarle o bien que ignore los *plugins* afectados, o que los ejecute al hacer el *build*:

```
<pluginManagement>
  <plugins>
    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.eclipse.m2e</groupId>
      <artifactId>lifecycle-mapping</artifactId>
      <version>1.0.0</version>
      <configuration>
        <lifecycleMappingMetadata>
          <pluginExecutions>
            <pluginExecution>
              <pluginExecutionFilter>
                <groupId>some-group-id</groupId>
                <artifactId>some-artifact-id</artifactId>
                <versionRange>[1.0.0,)</versionRange>
                <goals>
                  <goal>some-goal</goal>
                </goals>
              </pluginExecutionFilter>
              <action>
                <execute>
                  <runOnIncremental>false</runOnIncremental>
                </execute >
                <!-- o <ignore/> -->
              </action>
            </pluginExecution>
          </pluginExecutions>
        </lifecycleMappingMetadata>
      </configuration>
    </plugin>
  </plugins>
</pluginManagement>
```

Si haces `<ignore/>`, puedes tener que lanzar un `mvn package` "a mano" (aunque sea desde el Eclipse) cada tanto tiempo para que se ejecuten los pasos necesarios (por ejemplo generación automática de código).

---

<sup>1</sup> Al fin y al cabo están pensados para ejecutarse en un build de Maven que normalmente es un proceso que lanza una JVM, se ejecuta y cierra la JVM.